# Grab object id and insert into session storage Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session-cookies

I have a controller that populates a second drop-down box depending on the selection of the first, this works well although WebStorm sees it as a syntax error.
I know want to post the ID of the format fname to my session storage to use else where, however I have tried the code bellow and I see Value as

> [object Object]

if I use

```
sessionStorage.setItem('format', $scope.formats);
```

and

> undefined

if I use

sessionStorage.setItem('format', $scope.formats.id);

I have also tried

```
sessionStorage.setItem('format', $scope.formats.formatType.id);
```

I get nothing not even a empty value

how do I correctly add the ID to my format value in my session storage ?

**Full code**

```
FirstModule.controller('dropDown', function ($scope) {

$scope.productsandformats = [
    {
        "name": "staff",
        "format": [
            {"Fname": "bill", "id": "1"},
            {"Fname": "bob", "id": "2"},
            {"Fname": "tom", "id": "3"}
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "managers",
        "format": [
            {"Fname": "dick", "id": "4"},
            {"Fname": "jhon", "id": "5"}
        ]
    },

    {
        "name": "directors",
        "format": [
            {"Fname": "willy", "id": "6"}
        ]
    },


    {
        "name": "temp",
        "format": [
            {"Fname": "jeff", "id": "18"},
            {"Fname": "billy", "id": "19"}
        ]
    }];

$scope.productTypeChange = function () {
    $scope.formats = $scope.productsandformats.find(ps => ps.name == $scope.formData.ProductType.name)

    sessionStorage.setItem('format', $scope.formats.id);

}
```

});

To further more explain how I get the ID, The code bellow enables the user to select A fname from the name type for example if select staff you get bill, bob and tom then after you select one it,ll print out the selected name and fname including the fname id, the fname id is what i need to send to the session storage

HTML

```
<div class="radio col-sm-6" style="margin-top: 0 !important;">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.type" value="Create" >
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked">
        </span>
        Need to make a poster?
    </label>
</div>

<div class="radio col-sm-6">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" ng-model="formData.type" value="Preview">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">
        </span>
        Already have a poster?
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot store an `object`, you can only store a `string`.

To store an object you need to "stringify" it.

```
var jsonItem = JSON.stringify($scope.formats);
sessionStorage.setItem('format', jsonItem);
```

Then to retrieve it you need to parse it

```
var item = sessionStorage.getItem('format');
item = JSON.parse(item)
```

From MDN [Storage/setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

> `storage.setItem(keyName, keyValue);`
>
> **keyName** A DOMString containing the name of the key you want to
>   create/update.
>
> **keyValue** A DOMString containing the value you want to
>   give the key you are creating/updating.

**About finding the ID**

When you do

```
$scope.formats = $scope.productsandformats.find(ps => ps.name == 
 $scope.formData.ProductType.name)
```

You get an object with this structure

```
{
    "name": "staff",
    "format": [
        {"Fname": "bill", "id": "1"},
        {"Fname": "bob", "id": "2"},
        {"Fname": "tom", "id": "3"}
    ]
},
```

So i guess the id is contained inside `item.format[0].id` for the first item and so on for the subsequent items.

`format` is an array so you wont be able to directly access `id` if you don't first select which element of the array you want (eg. `format[0]`).

Comment: Ok, nice am getting while string atm not just ID but when i fix this ill accept, +1 for the information your a star

Comment: This is the best answer, I just need to find a way just to get the id

Comment: I expanded the answer to tackle the problem with the id

Comment: Just seen that, thanks mate. few more hours till the weekend. Ill accept answer as soon as i crack it. Ill update my question with the html aspect

Comment: Ahh just read your update about not being able to access the id in the array, ok thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 0):

So I used the answer above but to achieve the id I had to use this

```
 $scope.myFunc = function() {
        var jsonItem = JSON.parse($scope.formData.formatType.id);
        sessionStorage.setItem('format', jsonItem);
    }
```

@Bolza answer was good but I needed more so kept digging and experimenting